# Logic behind a UIButton insets (sizeToFit)

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uibutton

I create a UIButton *programmatically*. I'm expecting the call to `sizeToFit` to size my button with its title size (and font). But it shows an inset as can be seen with the gray area above and below the title.

[image: UIButton]

All insets value shows 0.0 (as they are supposed to be initialized with UIEdgeInsetsZero)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setTitle:@"Tap Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    btn.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [btn sizeToFit]; // Resize will set the width and height

    [self.view addSubview:btn]; 

    NSLog(@"%.2f %.2f %.2f", btn.imageEdgeInsets.top, btn.contentEdgeInsets.top, btn.titleEdgeInsets.top);
    // Previous statement output :
    // ... Sandbox[1764:59117] 0.00 0.00 0.00
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something. Where can I find these insets values ?

(this is with iOS 8.3)

**Update on sizeToFit**

Some comments lead me to be more specific: I know the default value for `contentEdgeInsets` is UIEdgeInsetsZero, as is stated in the apple documentation. My post suggests that somehow, different values are applied. 
I tested with two "empty" UIButton controls:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[btn sizeToFit]; 
[self.view addSubview:btn];

UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
btn2.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[btn2 sizeToFit];     
[self.view addSubview:btn2];

// Put some code next to move centers to display buttons properly
// ...
```

[image]

- UIButtonTypeCustom (gray background above): the control size after calling `sizeToFit` is 30x34
- UIButtonTypeSystem (purple background): 30x30

Some internal logic adapts the size, and I could not find where *this* value comes from. It is not reflected in the contentEdgeInsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug (21437476) and it has been fixed :

> Apple Developer Relations16-Sep-2015 09:51 PM
> We believe this issue has been addressed.  Please verify this issue with iOS 9 GM (Build: 13A344) and update your bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ with the results.
>
> iOS 9 GM (Build: 13A344)
> https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/
>
> Posted Date: Sept. 16th, 2015

It's also on [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/21437476) too.

Answer (score 0):

It is adding some extra spacing all around the button

try this

```
btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It will remove insets.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this. It seems it's related to the `contentEdgeInsets` only.

Answer (score 0):

Default value for imageEdgeInsets, contentEdgeInsets, titleEdgeInsets is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

Please use below code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTitle:@"Tap Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
btn.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[btn sizeToFit]; // Resize will set the width and height

NSLog(@"%.2f %.2f %.2f", btn.imageEdgeInsets.top, btn.contentEdgeInsets.top, btn.titleEdgeInsets.top);

// Previous statement output :
// ... Sandbox[1764:59117] 0.00 0.00 0.00

btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake( 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

[self.view addSubview:btn];
NSLog(@"%.2f %.2f %.2f", btn.imageEdgeInsets.top, btn.contentEdgeInsets.top, btn.titleEdgeInsets.top);
// Previous statement output :
// 0.00 10.00 0.00
```

Comment: Indeed explicitly setting a contentEdgeInsets seems to work...except when it is 0 (or UIEdgeInsetsZero) and this behavior is not documented. I can use a `UIEdgeInsetsMake( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);` to get only a 1 line pixel at bottom, but I still wonder where this default padding comes from.

Comment: Please check URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/contentEdgeInsets

Default velue is UIEdgeInsetsZero.